# escape environments inside listing environment reduce horizontal space between characters

Tags: listings

Why escape environments reduce horizontal space between characters? I tried both `escapechar` and `escapeinside`. See my code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings} 

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@]
    NEW: HardwareVersion 75.32.2 FirmwareVersion 532.23
    OLD: @\textcolor{red}{HardwareVersion 15.32.2}@ FirmwareVersion 323.12
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={@}{@}]
    NEW: HardwareVersion 75.32.2 FirmwareVersion 532.23
    OLD: @\textcolor{red}{HardwareVersion 15.32.2}@ FirmwareVersion 323.12
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thanks a lot :) yes indeed I mean horizontal. I already changed this in my description of the question.

Comment: Do you really want that awkward spacing anyway? I've always found it awful: look at NEW, for instance.

Comment: @egreg I would prefer same distance :)